# Is it possible to spoof touchscreen inputs without user interaction?

Tags: android, keyboard

Consider the following system:

- Stock Android 9, unrooted
- USB and wireless debugging unavailable
- screen permanently turned off

So basically a headless Android device.

**Question:** Is it possible to programmatically spoof touchscreen interactions on such a device, e.g. in order to force-close a firewall app without any actual user input?

If yes, how? If no, why not?

**Example:** The default method to do this manually is from the app info menu, i.e.

[image: Force-closing active apps by user input]

Similarly, inactive/background apps can be closed from the developer settings:

[image: Force-closing inactive apps by user input]

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a security question. You are asking how to provide inputs to an Android device other than the touch screen to navigate the UI.